# How do I make this Solve work faster?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I'm quite new to Mathematica and this code is taking forever to work.

Are there easy ways that will make this same code work much more quickly?

```
HMmatrix[n_] := Module[{A, a, constraints, vars, AAT, equations, sol},
  A = Table[a[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
  constraints = Table[a[i, j]^2 == 1, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}] // Flatten;
  vars = Table[a[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}] // Flatten;
  AAT = Dot[A, Transpose[A]];
  equations = Join[{AAT == n*IdentityMatrix[n]}, constraints];
  sol = Solve[equations, vars, Integers]; size = Length[sol]; 
  Return[size]]
```

Comment: It's the `Solve` that you need to speed up, not the `Module`.

Comment: How is that done?

Comment: It's non-trivial, but it narrows the focus of your question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: What is the expected usage? How large `n`? My guess is recasting as an ILP will be slow, but not as slow as the current version.

Comment: As much as reasonably possible. Hopefully I could find up to n=12 at least. How could I do that?

Comment: Maybe one can omit `Solve`. All your possible values for the variables are +1 or -1, right?. `n=12` means 144 variables. and not so many equations. Can you simply produce all possible matrices and variables ( via Tuples, Table or the variables with  `Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {n, n}]` and `Select` the right ones?.

Comment: HMmatrix2[n_] := Module[{rowpossibilities, matrices, hadamard, size},
      matrices = Tuples[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
      hadamard = 
       Select[matrices, Dot[#, Transpose[#]] == n*IdentityMatrix[n] &];
      size = Length[hadamard];
      Return[size]]

Comment: This works but as soon as n>4 I get an error for Tuples[{-1,1},{n,n}] saying Tuples::toomany: The length of the output of Tuples[{-1,1},{12,12}] should be a machine integer.

Comment: So do you want all of the answers? The number of the answers? Or just some answers? If you want the number of answers, I am sure it blows up with $n$. Even with $n=12$, I counted at least $2000 \times 12!$ solutions.

Comment: The next time you ask a question, it would be way more helpful to other users to include a little background on what you're trying to do, instead of just dumping code for others to look at.

Comment: I want the number of solutions for a given value of n.

Comment: So your real questions is "what are the number of unique matrices that satisfy this relation for varying $n$?"

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way to solve this problem quickly is to very thoroughly re-state the problem. I do not promise that this is a complete solution to the problem, but I hope it provides significant insight into how to approach finding any such complete solution.

From what I understood from the comments, we are looking for matrices consisting of only $-1$ and $+1$ which satisfy the equation:

$M \times M^T = n \times I_n$

Where $M$ is the square matrix in question, $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix, and $n$ is the number of rows or columns in $M$.

By the very nature of the problem, the diagonal elements will always turn out to be $n$ after the multiplication for any square matrix consisting of only 1s (plus or minus). Thus, we are concerned only about every non-diagonal element of the result.

Every single one of these elements meets the criteria that the row ($r$) and column ($c$) involved in forming it satisfy $r \cdot c = 0$.

Let us first find all such possible vectors. Assume $n=2$ for our starting case.

```
n = 2;
t = Tuples[{-1, 1}, {n}];
r = Outer[Dot, t, t, 1];
p = Position[r, 0];
```

Line by line, we set `n = 2`, we construct all possible 2-vectors consisting of `-1` or `1`, we dot product all of these vectors together to form a matrix `n`, which we then search for every `0` element and store their positions in `p`.

The matrix we are looking for, $M$, has the property that every row and column is present in `t`, and every possible multiple of these rows and columns has indices that are present in `p` together.

That is, if we look at `p` right now, it consists of:

> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}}

If we collect elements which are paired, we will find that matrices formed from them satisfy the original problem. That is to say that `t[[{1,2}]]`, `t[[{1,3}]]`, `t[[{2,4}]]`, and so on are solutions to the `n=2` case.

For `n=4` it is somewhat more complicated:

> {{1, 4}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {1, 10}, {1, 11}, {1, 13}, {2, 3}, {2, 
>     5}, {2, 8}, {2, 9}, {2, 12}, {2, 14}, {3, 2}, {3, 5}, {3, 8}, {3, 
>     9}, {3, 12}, {3, 15}, {4, 1}, {4, 6}, {4, 7}, {4, 10}, {4, 11}, {4, 
>     16}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 8}, {5, 9}, {5, 14}, {5, 15}, {6, 1}, {6, 
>     4}, {6, 7}, {6, 10}, {6, 13}, {6, 16}, {7, 1}, {7, 4}, {7, 6}, {7, 
>     11}, {7, 13}, {7, 16}, {8, 2}, {8, 3}, {8, 5}, {8, 12}, {8, 14}, {8,
>      15}, {9, 2}, {9, 3}, {9, 5}, {9, 12}, {9, 14}, {9, 15}, {10, 
>     1}, {10, 4}, {10, 6}, {10, 11}, {10, 13}, {10, 16}, {11, 1}, {11, 
>     4}, {11, 7}, {11, 10}, {11, 13}, {11, 16}, {12, 2}, {12, 3}, {12, 
>     8}, {12, 9}, {12, 14}, {12, 15}, {13, 1}, {13, 6}, {13, 7}, {13, 
>     10}, {13, 11}, {13, 16}, {14, 2}, {14, 5}, {14, 8}, {14, 9}, {14, 
>     12}, {14, 15}, {15, 3}, {15, 5}, {15, 8}, {15, 9}, {15, 12}, {15, 
>     14}, {16, 4}, {16, 6}, {16, 7}, {16, 10}, {16, 11}, {16, 13}}

If we just pick randomly from these, we will not get a solution except by chance. However, if we pick in turn so that every new index appears in a pair with every prior chosen index, we can get a solution. One example of such is `t[[{1,4,6,7}]]`:

> {{-1, -1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1, -1}}

We can automate this process significantly by recognizing this as a graph problem and applying appropriate functions.

```
g = Graph[Evaluate[Map[DirectedEdge @@ # &, p]]];
c = FindClique[g, {n}, All]
```

> {{10, 11, 13, 16}, {7, 11, 13, 16}, {6, 10, 13, 16}, {6, 7, 13, 
>     16}, {4, 10, 11, 16}, {4, 7, 11, 16}, {4, 6, 10, 16}, {4, 6, 7, 
>     16}, {9, 12, 14, 15}, {8, 12, 14, 15}, {5, 9, 14, 15}, {5, 8, 14, 
>     15}, {3, 9, 12, 15}, {3, 8, 12, 15}, {3, 5, 9, 15}, {3, 5, 8, 
>     15}, {2, 9, 12, 14}, {2, 8, 12, 14}, {2, 5, 9, 14}, {2, 5, 8, 
>     14}, {2, 3, 9, 12}, {2, 3, 8, 12}, {2, 3, 5, 9}, {2, 3, 5, 8}, {1, 
>     10, 11, 13}, {1, 7, 11, 13}, {1, 6, 10, 13}, {1, 6, 7, 13}, {1, 4, 
>     10, 11}, {1, 4, 7, 11}, {1, 4, 6, 10}, {1, 4, 6, 7}}

That said, I am not 100% familiar with the mathematics involved here as I do not have much personal experience with graph theory. I am not going to claim that these are all of the solutions to this problem, but it does appear that each of these cliques is an individual solution to the problem.

This should be generally faster than attempting to directly solve larger cases. However, it is still rather slow. The first solution it can find reasonably quickly is:

> {{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1, -1, 
>   -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 
>     1}, {-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1}, {-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 
>     1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 
>     1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1, 
>     1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 
>     1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1, 
>     1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
>     1, -1, -1, 1}}

Interestingly, there are apparently no solutions for $n=6$ or $n=10$. I haven't been able to spend the time to check the $n=14$ case. There are definitely solutions for 2, 4, 8, and 12, though exactly how many there are for 12 is not something I've spent the time to check.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer. The conjecture is that there are solutions for n=1,2,4,8,12,16,...,4n,...

Comment: There are a couple of things I am slightly confused about. First, How can this be pictured as a graph theory problem? Secondly, since there is “one” solution for n=8, does that mean there are 8C2 solutions as there are 8C2 ways of reordering the rows?

Comment: It's a graph theory problem because it turns into a problem where we are searching for groups of individual rows that exhibit a specific property in relation to each other. We can construct a graph of that relation and then use clique-finding to solve the problem. The "one" solution I mentioned would correspond to $8!$ solutions, since any valid permutation would suffice and all of the rows are unique. Hypothetically, the transpose of any of these permutations should also work, but I think there's a curiosity that the matrix can be arranged to form any of its transposes (haven't checked).

Comment: Actually, re-checking the `n=8` solution, I retract that claim. I have no idea where that came from. I suspect I accidentally limited the number of cliques in `FindClique` there. There are quite a few, around 4954521600, counting permutations.

Comment: I have done research and up to permutation of rows, columns, negation, there is only meant to be one solution for n=1,2,4,8

Comment: @Anteater23 I haven't checked them extremely thoroughly, but it's possible that they all are the same solution under those assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

Not a full answer...

I took what proved to be a similar approach as @eyorble, in that I turn it into a graph problem.

I also just demonstrate how to get a lot of solutions, but not the guaranteed total number of solutions. I think the total number blows up combinatorically, so probably not worth counting.

The main idea is that the matrix $A$ is invertible, with vector elements that almost form an orthonormal basis. For $a$ and $b$ in $A$, $a.b$ is either $n$ or $0$.

Let the first vector $a_{1}$ be the vector $[{1,1,....,1}]$ Then every other vector must have an equal number of $1$ and $-1$. Create all of those permutations. Let $n=12$

```
n = 12; 
pp = Permutations[Flatten@{Table[1, {n/2}], Table[-1, {n/2}]}];
```

Take the dot product of all of them, but turning it into an adjacency matrix where it is a $1$ if the dot product is zero, and zero otherwise.

```
gg = Outer[If[Dot[#1, #2] != 0, 0, 1] &, pp, pp, 1];//Timing
(* {0.875, Null} *)
```

Now find 2000 cliques (meaning 2000 solutions for $A$) that have exactly 11 nodes.

```
res = FindClique[AdjacencyGraph@gg, {n - 1}, 2000]; // Timing

(* {0.125, Null} *)

Length@res
(* 2000 *)
```

If you just run `FindClique[AdjacencyGraph@gg]` it takes much longer, and the largest clique also has 11 elements.

There are no answers with this method for $n=14$, and it blows up on $n=16$. I am pretty sure that there's a constructive method to get to higher dimensions without having to do a brute force search, as in this method.

Comment: So can it be represented by a graph because for a a given nxn matrix there are n rows to choose - the rows represent the nodes and two nodes connected if their dot product is zero. So the aim is to find a fully-connected graph?

Comment: Correct. In my case, I am fixing the first row to be all 1's, which forces the remaining $n-1$ rows to all have an equal number of 1's and -1's, reducing the search space (but leaving solutions undiscovered?) But really , you shouldn't want the answers, you should just want the number of answers, which is a different question with likely a different solution approach.

Comment: If I wanted the total number of possibilities for a given n should I not insist that the first row is all 1’s? Then I find the number of cliques and multiply by n! since that is the number of ways we can rearrange the n “row options”?